# How to declare scalar variable?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@refSlips".'

Code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

SqlCommand aaa = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ConsultationTB VALUES('" + consultationTb.Text + "','" + dateTb.Text + "','" + bodytempTb.Text + "','" + paccodeTb.Text + "', @refSlips ", con);

string RadButt = string.Empty;

if (ForAdmission.Checked)
{
    RadButt = "For Admission";
}
else if (ForLabTest.Checked)
{
    RadButt = "For Laboratory Test";
}
else if (BothRb.Checked)
{
    RadButt = "Both";
}
else if (NotAppRb.Checked)
{
    RadButt = "Not Applicable";
}
     
con.Open();
aaa.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

getCONNO();

ForAdmission.Checked = false;
ForLabTest.Checked = false;
BothRb.Checked = false;
NotAppRb.Checked = false;
```

Comment: [**SQL Injection alert**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Can you explain what that `@refSlips` is doing in *your* code? Hint: you need more of them

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @HansKeﬆing radio button or radButt was refslips  sorry i forgot connecting refslips to radbutt. [aaa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@refSlips", RadButt);] i have now added  this to the code but a new error arises [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '@refSlips'.'] . Should i just get rid of ref slips? Thank you for helping everyone i am still new to coding.

Comment: guys good news im very happy i solved it  [ + "', @refSlips)" , con);]  the problem was the parenthesis after refslips.  the problem i was trying to solve for 2 days was just a simple closing parenthesis . i dont know if i wanna cry or laugh hahahha

Comment: We all have that occasionally . But please also replace the injected values with parameters, using correct datatypes

Comment: Hi @JDHahaha , glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as  an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

[ + "', @refSlips)" , con);] the problem was the parenthesis after refslips.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).